# How to get Eclipse to show Exceptions when errors occur?

Tags: android, eclipse, exception

I am coding up an Android app and sometimes exceptions occur. So while I am debugging, an exception occurs, the IDE changes into Debug perspective and Eclipse throws up an absolutely useless Class Editor with its Source Not Found.

[image]

How do I get Eclipse to actually tell me the specific exception that occurred.

Comment: Not sure if I understood this correctly, but I think you're just looking for LogCat. It's under Window -> Show View -> LogCat. It shows real time info coming from your emulator / hooked up phone, including exceptions. It even shows where the exception occurs if you just click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want either **Error Log** or **Logcat**

If those windows are hidden, you can show them:

Window --> Show View

Comment: If you still have trouble, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866565/how-can-i-see-the-error-log-logcat-for-android-in-eclipse